# Streamlit widgets doesn't display in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

I'm trying to create streamlit widgets in Jupyter Notebook but when executing the following code nothing happens.

```
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

age = st.selectbox("Choose your age: ", np.arange(18, 66, 1))
```

According to the [following article](https://towardsdatascience.com/quickly-build-and-deploy-an-application-with-streamlit-988ca08c7e83) a SelectBox like this should be created.

[image]
But in my code I only get to know that print(age) is 18. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't run the code from a notebook. You create a python script with your code and then use this command from a shell: streamlit run yourfile.py
the output will show up in the shell

[image]

Reason for this is that streamlit runs on the main thread so it would block the jupyter kernal, you won't be able to use the notebook while the streamlit app is running. However, if you really want to stay inside Jupyter to run the app, you can run the command in a cell, like this !streamlit run yourfile.py

Comment: So, streamlit is not meant for such tasks like presenting your work for other users? For example we cannot see these widgets when the project is loaded into github environment? I can only run it in my local machine and see the results?

Comment: I think streamlit can still be used for presentations, maybe not in github however. It just doesn't work well with Jupyter or other notebooks as it will take over the thread. You won't be able to use the other cells while it is running. As a workaround, if you are running from a Linux host, you may try to use  `!streamlit run yourfile.py &`
The ampersand allows the command to run in the background. I only run Jupyter on windows so I can't try this myself. Otherwise, I think you will have to load this on a server with Python installed to use it for presenting your work.

Comment: Another option is to publish the file on github and let the user run the file locally. Here is an example I found:
`streamlit run https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streamlit/demo-self-driving/master/app.py`
The user would have to install the proper libraries, or install conda, so this may be a bit more complicated...

Comment: you can get a few more ideas here: https://towardsdatascience.com/quickly-build-and-deploy-an-application-with-streamlit-988ca08c7e83

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I've developed my code in Jypyter Notebook and created a python script, as you mentioned. However, when I run the command: streamlit run 'the file'.py in anaconda prompt, the following error occurs.

'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've reinstalled streamlit in the command prompt, but the error still occurs. Could you please help me solve it?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89049)